# XeLaTeX: \mathrm in a footnote uses a different typeface from that specified by \setmathfont

Tags: xetex

In the following XeLaTeX example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\begin{document}
$\mathrm{d}$: d\footnote{$\mathrm{d}$: d}
\end{document}
```

`\mathrm` in the main text is fine (both d's look the same), whereas that in the footnote doesn't use the correct typeface (the first d is different). What's happening here and how do I get around it?

[image: different mathrm]

Comment: They look the same to me: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OjBgo.png)

Comment: The screenshot of my footnote added

Comment: That's different from mine. What versions of `fontspec` and `unicode-math` do you have? You find them in the log file

Comment: @egreg fontspec 2.4c and unicode-math 0.7f. I'm installing MacTeX 2016 now and will see if the problem disappears.

Comment: Here `Package: fontspec 2016/02/01 v2.5a` and `Package: unicode-math 2015/09/24 v0.8c`. On the other hand, the letter “d” in Libertinus Serif and in Libertinus Math seem to have distinct forms, that show more at small sizes. Indeed the problem reappears if you use `\symrm` instead of `\mathrm`.

Comment: @egreg The problem does disappear with the latest version of both packages. Problem solved! Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved by a software update